# Create group based on if values have been decreasing/increasing for more than 3 consequential days Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe and I want to create new groupings every time the values have been decreasing or increasing for 3 consequential days.

Data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2022-09-01', '2022-09-02', ...], 'value': [10, 8, ...]})
```

Example:

Dataframe:

| date | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-09-01 | 10 |
| 2022-09-02 | 8 |
| 2022-09-03 | 9 |
| 2022-09-04 | 8 |
| 2022-09-05 | 6 |
| 2022-09-06 | 2 |
| 2022-09-07 | 4 |
| 2022-09-08 | 5 |
| 2022-09-09 | 6 |
| 2022-09-10 | 5 |
| 2022-09-11 | 8 |
| 2022-09-12 | 9 |
| 2022-09-13 | 10 |
| 2022-09-14 | 11 |
| 2022-09-15 | 2 |

Desired output:

| date | value | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-01 | 10 | 1 |
| 2022-09-02 | 8 | 1 |
| 2022-09-03 | 9 | 1 |
| 2022-09-04 | 8 | 1 |
| 2022-09-05 | 6 | 1 |
| 2022-09-06 | 2 | 1 |
| 2022-09-07 | 4 | 2 |
| 2022-09-08 | 5 | 2 |
| 2022-09-09 | 6 | 2 |
| 2022-09-10 | 5 | 3 |
| 2022-09-11 | 8 | 3 |
| 2022-09-12 | 9 | 3 |
| 2022-09-13 | 10 | 3 |
| 2022-09-14 | 11 | 4 |
| 2022-09-15 | 2 | 4 |

I tried to create another column which shows 1 for an increase and -1 for a decrease. Then my plan was to sum values until the sum is more than 3 or less than 3, and somehow to create a grouping based on that. However I did not come any further....

```
l = []
for i in range(len(df['value'])-1):
    if (df['value'][i + 1]) > (df['value'][i]):
        l.append(1)
    elif (df['value'][i + 1]) < (df['value'][i]):
        l.append(-1)
    else:
        l.append(0)
```

My main goal is then to be able to create linear slopes (similar like the red lines in the picture) which have the same slope until the three consequential days appear, after which the slope is changed.

[image]

Comment: I am not really understand the logic behind your desired `output`. (1) The first 3 values decrease and then increase, how are they in the same group? (2) What happen if from 2022-07 to 2022-09-09 the value increase from 4-5-4? (3) Why 2022-09-14 value 11 is in gr `4`. Is this ur typo or there is some logic behind?

Comment: Hi, my logic is that if the values are going the same direction (increase or decrease) for >=3 days in a row, they should belong to the same group. I am not sure if my desired output has typos. But for example if the values are going up for 10 days in a row, these should all belong to the same group, only when values decrease for more than 3 days the new group should be assigned.

Comment: I added a picture in the description for more understanding of the problem

Comment: Take the first 5 rows, value is 10 `down` to 8 then `up` to 9 then `down` for 8, 6, 2. According to your logic then from 2022-09-03 to 2022-09-06 they should be in the same group (value decrease from 9-8-6-2), but the first two rows (10 and 8) should `NOT` belong to any group because they don't have any minimum 3 consecutive increase/decrease. However, in your desired `output`, you still put the first 2 rows in group `1`. That's why I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule you want to avoid iterating over the rows of a dataframe. Instead attemp to always use inbuild functions. In this case start by computing the differences using `diff`

```
df['delta'] = -df.value.diff(-1)
```

the sing of the difference can then be computed using `np.sign`

```
df['delta_sign'] = np.sign(df.delta)
```

since the problem calls for looking at 3 consecutive days and thus at 2 consecutive differences we need to create a rolling window and sum over it

```
df['three_set_behaviour']=df.delta_sign.rolling(2).sum().shift(-1)
```

note that the `shift(-1)` is required as pandas always ankers the result of the aggregation on the window to the right of the window and we want it on the left.

Now as only three continuous increases/decreases matter for group behaviour we need to first eliminate all other entries

```
df.loc[abs(df.three_set_behaviour) != 2,'three_set_behaviour'] = np.nan
```

and fill them with the behaviour dictaminated by the previous three grouping

```
df.three_set_behaviour = df.three_set_behaviour.ffill()
```

Note that your problem leaves undefined what should happen with the values till the first three grouping. On option would be to impose on them the behaviour of the first grouping in the time series

```
df.three_set_behaviour = df.three_set_behaviour.bfill()
```

With `three_set_behaviour` now containing a direction for all entries, changes to direction and thus group can be computed using

```
df['group_change'] = df.three_set_behaviour != df.three_set_behaviour.shift(1)
```

of which the cumulative sum can be made in order to get the current group.

```
df['group'] = df.group_change.cumsum()
```

This results in `df` containing

| value | delta | delta_sign | three_set_behaviour | group_change | group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | -2.0 | -1.0 | -2.0 | True | 1 |
| 8 | 1.0 | 1.0 | -2.0 | False | 1 |
| 9 | -1.0 | -1.0 | -2.0 | False | 1 |
| 8 | -2.0 | -1.0 | -2.0 | False | 1 |
| 6 | -4.0 | -1.0 | -2.0 | False | 1 |
| 2 | 2.0 | 1.0 | 2.0 | True | 2 |
| 4 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 2.0 | False | 2 |
| 5 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 2.0 | False | 2 |
| 6 | -1.0 | -1.0 | 2.0 | False | 2 |
| 5 | 3.0 | 1.0 | 2.0 | False | 2 |
| 8 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 2.0 | False | 2 |
| 9 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 2.0 | False | 2 |
| 10 | -5.0 | -1.0 | -2.0 | True | 3 |
| 5 | -3.0 | -1.0 | -2.0 | False | 3 |
| 2 | nan | nan | -2.0 | False | 3 |

Note that I have taken the liberty of changing the second to last value in your example to make it show also 3 fallin values.